# Save multiple directory paths to file and upon restart read from it to populate variables

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, text-parsing

I have a program which in order to function needs the user to input two directories (e.g. the Desktop and Picture directory). This works, but upon closing and relaunching the program, the user needs to re-enter the directories, as the program does not remember the directories from the last time it ran. Obviously.

Now my plan was to create a file to which the program writes the directories so that once the user launches the program it checks if the file exists and if so reads it and gets the two directories it needs.

I tried creating a plain .txt, but as there are two directories and either one or the other can be written to the .txt first it was hard to read from it and get the correct directory. To visualize my .txt can look like this:

`C://Dir1 C://Dir2`
[image: See here]

or

`C://Dir2 C://Dir1` [image: See here]

depending on which directory the user selected first.

[image: See here]

Tl;Dr I want to save two directories for consequent launches of the program, but when reading the two directories I need to be able to know which directory is which.

I am working with .NET Core 3.1

Comment: Is it just the plain desktop and pictures directories and not a subdirectory? If so, why not just use [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netcore-3.1) with the [`Environment.SpecialFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netcore-3.1#examples) enum? Then the user doesn't need to do anything.

Comment: just also save the type info, eg, key value paras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> either one or the other can be written to the .txt first

This is a wrong assumption. You decide in your code in which order they are written and you always write both of them, never one of them only.

Example code for writing:

```
string a = null;
string b = "c:\\something";
File.WriteAllText("myconfig.txt", a+ "\r\n" + b);
```

Example code for reading:

```
string[] filecontent = File.ReadAllLines("myconfig.txt");
a = filecontent[0];
if (a==string.Empty) a = null;
b = filecontent[1];
if (b==string.Empty) b = null;
Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```